# Return String error (missing return statement after returned)

Tags: java

I had problem returning the string although I've placed both return statements inside the if else condition.

```
public String getAvailableRooms(int numofGuest)
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<rooms.length; i++)
    {
        if(rooms[i].getstatusRoom()==false)
            rooms[i].getnumofBeds();
    }
    String temp =  "The available room is room " + i + "and the number of beds " + rooms[i].getnumofBeds();
    if (rooms[i].getnumofBeds() >= numofGuest)
        return temp;
    else if (numofGuest> 4)
        return "Theres no available room";      
}
```

Comment: What should your method return if neither of those conditions is true?

Comment: Also the logic in your code does not make sense. Inside your loop you're calling `getnumofBeds` but not doing anything with the result. Then after the loop, `i` will be just past the end of your array, but you're still trying to use it as an array index.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything if both of your `if` conditions are false i.e. you are missing and `else` statement. Try the following, it should work for you.(because there are only 2 conditions)

```
if (some_condition)
    return temp;
else
    return "Theres no available room";
```

If the above doesn't work, try putting an `else` statement in your `if` condition.

Comment: This will result in an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @AndyTurner Corrected